# Build dynamic Mongo Query from the Json input -java

Tags: java, json, mongodb

```
[

{
  "field_name": "name",
  "field_type": "string",
  "field_value": "peter",
  "operator": "equal",
  "condition": "or"
},{
  "field_name": "status",
  "field_type": "string",
  "field_value": "draft",
  "operator": "equal",
  "condition": "and"
}
{
  "field_name": "created",
  "field_type": "date",
  "field_value": "12-06-2012",
  "operator": "greaterthan",
  "condition": ""
}]
```

provided the json to the java controller, need to build the mongo DB query with the
filter options given in the above json as,

```
Query query=new Query();
query.addCriteria (Criteria.where("name").is("peter").or("status").is("draft").and("created").gt(12-06-2012))
mongoOperations.find(query,classname.class)
```

Please help me to iterate the json and build the query with multiple filters.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you like to use the conditions? Did you consider [precedence of boolean](https://www.bouraspage.com/repository/algorithmic-thinking/what-is-the-order-of-precedence-of-logical-operators) operators?

Comment: `"12-06-2012"` is not a `Date`, it is a string! You would also need to specify the format or provide a `Date` object.

Comment: yes the condition we can pass it as we like but my worry is to build the query dynamically   , conditions are like "and", "or", etc and operator as "like","gt","lt"